# Create MySQL Trigger getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error

I am trying to create a trigger, which I have never done before, and this is the code I am putting in.

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'NewMember' AFTER INSERT ON 'phplist_user_user'
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO phplist_listuser (userid,listid) VALUES (NEW.id, '2');
END;$$
```

When I try and run the SQL, I get this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''NewMember' AFTER INSERT ON 'phplist_user_user'
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT I' at line 1
```

I got this code from phpmyAdmin's website. I don't know what is wrong, can someone please help? Like I said, I have NEVER done this before. Thanks in advance.

I tried adding the ticks instead and this is what I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `NewMember` AFTER INSERT ON `phplist_user_user`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO `phplist_listuser` (`userid`,`listid`) VALUES (NEW.id, '2');
END;$$
```

I am now getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

phpMyAdmin is acting as if there is something wrong in the INSERT INTO section, there is an exclamation mark beside it and when I click on it, it takes me to try and explain the error. I am literally typing it how MySQL is telling me to fix it. I have tried multiple combinations with the ticks, having the columns in ticks and not, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use ticks, not single quotes for identifiers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `NewMember` AFTER INSERT ON `phplist_user_user`
```

Comment: I tried that, please view the above edits. Thanks, I saw that in some other tutorials, I just never really thought about the difference!